# Force all lines into regular intervals so pages back up each other

Tags: line-spacing, layout, grid-typesetting

Bringhurst writes in *The Elements of Typographic Style*:

[image: bringhurst]

How can such an effect be achieved? Even when manually redefining all spaces, skips and heights to be multiples of the same number and have no rubber. But then still images, equations, and other things might have different proportions and shift everything.

Is such an effect possible in LaTeX? Is there a package for it?

Comment: This has come up previously.  The question is what are you willing to give up?  Display math?  Itemize?  Font size changes?  Figures and tables?  Footnotes?

Comment: Is there a comprehensive list with all the options somewhere? Someone added the tag "grid-typesetting" which is already very helpful, but I did not as of yet find the "one canonical post".

Comment: BTW, all these subheads could by done by using a \strut before changing the font size.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\gridspacer}[1]% #1 = special text
{\ifhmode\par\fi\leavevmode\bgroup
  \setbox0=\vtop{#1\null}%
  \dimen0=\ht\strutbox
  \loop \ifdim\dimen0<\ht0\relax \advance\dimen0 by \baselineskip \repeat
  \dimen1=\dp\strutbox
  \loop \ifdim\dimen1<\dp0\relax \advance\dimen1 by \baselineskip \repeat
  \advance\dimen1 by -\baselineskip
  \strut% top baseline
  \par\vskip\dimexpr \dimen0+\dimen1-2\baselineskip-\parskip\relax
  \noindent\strut% bottom basline
  \raisebox{\dimexpr \dimen1-\dp\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox0}\allowbreak
\egroup}


\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
\begin{paracol}{2}% side by side comparison
\lipsum[1-2]
\switchcolumn
\gridspacer{\section{Section}}
A line of text.% not indented

\noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{0.5pt}

Some text here
\gridspacer{\begin{equation}
  x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \int_0^\infty x^{-2} \,dx
  \end{equation}}
with some additional remarks.

\noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{0.5pt}

\gridspacer{\tiny \lipsum[2]}
\noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{0.5pt}

\dimen0=\baselineskip
{\tiny\baselineskip=\dimen0 \lipsum[2]}
\noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{0.5pt}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just for fun, add an equation with a fraction having a square root in the numerator.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - According to `\vtop`, the baseline is located above the equation.  Aligning the baseline obviously won't help align the equation.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't paying close enough attention and spaced over the `\vtop`.  Indeed, that wouldn't help grid-align a display with a fraction.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Anyway, the goal was to align the text after special inclusions, not necessarily the inclusions themselves.

Comment: Your macro breaks for me if it is used near/at a pagebreak -- the contents overflow into the top margin. I think you need a `\penalty10000` before the `\vskip` to fix it, to keep the "top part" and "bottom part" on the same page.

Comment: One would have to break the paragraph into two boxes and align each one.  Not sure whether to align the top or bottom on the second page.